# Open set in a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

A subset $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is open if for every point $x \in U$ there exists a real number $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ is contained in $U$.

So let's say I have $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and I only know it is non-empty. My question is: what does it mean to be open in a subset (in this case, $K$) of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? How do I modify the definition accordingly?

Comment: Let $U \subset K$. We say $U$ is open in $K$ if $B_\epsilon \cap K \subset U$. The more general case is the [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology).

Comment: @GabrielC.Barbosa Where is the ball centered around?

Comment: It is the same ball you mentioned. The criteria is the same but including the intersection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V\subset K$ is open in $K$, if there is an open set $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ such that $V = K\cap U$. The open sets in $K$ are said to form the so-called **subspace topology**.

Answer (score 0):

A subset $U$ is open in $X$ iff

$$\forall u \in U: \exists r>0: B_X(u,r):=\{x \in X: d(x,u) < r\} \subseteq U$$

A subset $U \subseteq K$ is open in $K$ iff

$$\forall u \in U: \exists r>0: B_K(u,r):=\{x \in K: d(x,u) < r\} \subseteq U$$

It's the same exept that we consider the distance of to $u$ is limited to only those in $K$, our new "universe".

It turns out that is equivalent to giving $K$ the so-called [subspace-topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology) as used in general topology.